# Pairwise Loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have the following toy matrix in R (for demonstration purposes)

```
m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), ncol = 2, byrow = FALSE)
```

and I am trying to conduct a for loop to get all the pairwise elements.
My result should be:

```
(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(3,4),(3,5),(3,6)
```

In other words, the pairwise elements would be:

```
(m[1,1],m[1,2])
(m[1,1],m[2,2])
(m[1,1],m[3,2])
(m[2,1],m[1,2])
(m[2,1],m[2,2])
(m[2,1],m[3,2])
(m[3,1],m[1,2])
(m[3,1],m[2,2])
(m[3,1],m[3,2])
```

I have the function set up to calculate the distances between them (not a predefined R-function for distances) but I need to be able to iterate using for-loops to get these combinations so I can call my distance function for these sets of points.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

edit: so for each of these pairwise elements, I will be creating a matrix to store a distance between them, ie,

```
distance.matrix <- matrix(NA, ncol = nrow(m), nrow = nrow(m))
#insert for loops here
distance.matrix[i,j] <- my.distance.measurement.function(m[1,1],m[1,2]) #for the first pairwise combination
```

Answer (score 1):

like this?

```
unlist(lapply(m[,1], function(x) paste0("(", x, ",", m[, 2], ")")))

[1] "(1,4)" "(1,5)" "(1,6)" "(2,4)" "(2,5)" "(2,6)" "(3,4)" "(3,5)" "(3,6)"
```

Comment: not quite. I need to able to use for loop to grab the elements like this though. For example, for the point (1,4) ,  I need to use that point to calculate a distance such as dist <- sqrt(1^2 + 4^2) and I will store each distance measurement from each pairwise element in a matrix